# Changes to the User Permissions Not saving

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am use drupal 6.

it seems like permission page can not save too many settings.

I have try to save permission setting, but it is just not saved into DB.
I have found out this is due to "too many fields". (use content permission module).
if i uncheck some fields, and then checking lesser fields, permission will be saved.

for example, if I am unchecking 2 check boxes, then checking one check box, permission will be saved.

does any one know which function the permission page used to insert result into db?

my php memory limit is 256M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function that saves the permissions in the database is [user_admin_perm_submit()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/user_admin_perm_submit/6).

```
function user_admin_perm_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Save permissions:
  $result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {role}');
  while ($role = db_fetch_object($result)) {
    if (isset($form_state['values'][$role->rid])) {
      // Delete, so if we clear every checkbox we reset that role;
      // otherwise permissions are active and denied everywhere.
      db_query('DELETE FROM {permission} WHERE rid = %d', $role->rid);
      $form_state['values'][$role->rid] = array_filter($form_state['values'][$role->rid]);
      if (count($form_state['values'][$role->rid])) {
        db_query("INSERT INTO {permission} (rid, perm) VALUES (%d, '%s')", $role->rid, implode(', ', array_keys($form_state['values'][$role->rid])));
      }
    }
  }

  drupal_set_message(t('The changes have been saved.'));

  // Clear the cached pages
  cache_clear_all();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to adjust the max_input_vars in php.ini.  The usual default is 1000, but with a lot of modules, the Drupal permissions page easily eclipses this.  Just add another zero and make it 10000 if you have access to php.ini and restart apache.  The location of the php.ini file depends on your server configuration.

I had the same issue, with no errors in the error log, and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

There is a good explanation of the issue that you are having here: http://2bits.com/drupal/drupal-not-saving-admin-pages-large-number-input-fields.html

Answer (score 1):

Change the size of the db table? Sounds like its truncating.

Comment: how to do that? by the way , i have dumped out whole permission table, it only 16090 byte, and where can i check a table size. my db is mysql

Comment: Change its type to long text with a database client like mysql in ssh or HeidiSQL gui

Comment: drupal's default type is longtype for permission type.